# Compiler Error C2664

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, compiler-errors

Having trouble with this compiler error, I can't figure out what its moaning about. If anyone could help I will be very grateful. Here is the error:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'CPropertyPage::CPropertyPage(UINT,UINT,DWORD)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'CWnd *' to 'UINT'   c:\users\bnason.prolec\documents\visual studio 2005\projects\autorepair1\autorepair1\customerinformationdlg.cpp 20
```

and here is the code that seems to be causing it:

```
CRepairOrderSheet::CRepairOrderSheet(LPCTSTR pszCaption, CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT iSelectPage)
    :CPropertySheet(pszCaption, pParentWnd, iSelectPage)
{
        this->AddPage(&dlgCustomerInformation);
        this->AddPage(&dlgJobsAndParts);
        this->AddPage(&dlgRepairSummary);

}
```

Comment: I doubt that's the code it is complaining about.  Find a CPropertyPage constructor at line 20.

Answer (score 2):

The `CPropertyPage` constructor takes three parameters: `UINT`, `UINT`, and `DWORD`. It's not clear whether your `CRepairOrderSheet` derives from `CPropertyPage` or `CPropertySheet` (information not provided in question), but the compiler thinks you're trying to construct a `CPropertyPage`. You are passing it `LPCTSTR`, `CWnd*` and `UINT`. The compiler cannot get the types to match up.